# Shopify private app api post request

Tags: shopify, navision, dynamics-nav

I am writing a private integration app from MS NAV to shopify api. I can use the api for Get Request, e.g. 
https://API_KEY:PASSWORD@wolf-wiegand-and-davis1433.myshopify.com/admin/orders.xml

However, the post request doesn't work for this formate: https://API_KEY:PASSWORD@wolf-wiegand-and-davis1433.myshopify.com/admin/products.xml.

I got a 403 status error.

anyone knows what could be wrong? or the api doesn't support post for the request.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your app's permissions have been corrupted. Creating a new app will give you credentials that should include all permissions.

Comment: (Note that Samuel here is on the Shopify dev yeam.)

Answer (score 0):

the response xml, it seems a permision issue :

You do not have products write permissions.